# How can I not send Null to database while using Update

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

If i need to just update one column do i have to give other column previous value or i can just give give the column i need to change and not null values to update in database .. here is procedure  code what can i do to this procedure so that i can just need to insert the value i want to update ...

```
 ALTER procedure [dbo].[Customer_update] 
( @Id int,
@Firstname nvarchar(40)=,
@Lastname nvarchar(40)=,
@City nvarchar(40)=null,
@Country nvarchar(40)=null,
@Phone nvarchar(20)=null

)
as 
begin 
update Customer set FirstName=@Firstname,LastName=@Lastname,City=@City,Country=@Country,Phone=@Phone where Id=@Id 
end
```

Comment: If your asking how to keep the existing value if one of the params is null then - `set FirstName=isnull(@Firstname, FirstName), ...`

Comment: no i mean If i need to update one column and just want to insert  the particular value and other value will be saved as previous value in column .... for example 
I want to Update FirstName and Lastname but other column are do not  need to be updated so what can i do so that i just need to insert the column i want to get  updated

Comment: The line i posted says *`make firstname the value of @Firstname unless @Firstname is null in which case use the current value`* - this is the best way to do it without a bunch of IF/ELSE.

Comment: @AlexK.I didnot understood can you edit on my procedure and explain ....

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you don't need to update all the columns. You can update just the columns you want and remove the others you aren't updating

Comment: @simplycoding but how i dont get you in this procedure i have to pass every parameter a value so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost have it and as Alex K pointed out in the comment above, the most elegant way to handle optional updates is to allow null parameters and update what is sent over.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Customer_update] 
    (@Id INT,
     @Firstname NVARCHAR(40) = NULL,
     @Lastname NVARCHAR(40) = NULL,
     @City NVARCHAR(40) = NULL,
     @Country NVARCHAR(40) = NULL,
     @Phone NVARCHAR(20) = NULL)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Customer 
    SET FirstName = ISNULL(@Firstname, FirstName)... 
    WHERE Id = @Id 
END
```

In order to use this in client code with nullable fields, simply omit the parameter altogether or let nulls pass through (one caveat to this is when you really need to set the field to null in which case the field should probably not be nullable. Then you can implicitly send a null over and the field will be set to the proper value)

Nullable fields allow you to omit parameters from a stored procedure call and still perform the operation. This is useful when you need make changes and do not want to impact existing applications, as long as the nullable fields are not required.

Are you asking about Insert/Update in one operation?

Some people do "upserts". I personally do not like having one operation for insert/updates. I feel the client should already know what operation should be performed, also, having one update and one insert procedure makes the procedures more transparent and easier to auto generate.

However, if that is what you were asking then you would create a procedure similar to the one below:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Customer_update] 
    (@Id INT = NULL,
     @Firstname NVARCHAR(40) = NULL,
     @Lastname NVARCHAR(40) = NULL
     @City NVARCHAR(40) = NULL
     @Country NVARCHAR(40) = NULL
     @Phone NVARCHAR(20) = NULL)
AS
BEGIN
    IF (@Id IS NULL) 
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Customer...
        SET @ID = @@SCOPE_IDENTITY
    END 
    ELSE BEGIN
        UPDATE Customer 
        SET FirtName = ISNULL(@FirstName, FirstName)
        WHERE Id = @Id
    END

    SELECT * 
    FROM Customer 
    WHERE Id = @Id
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use ISNULL on each column:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[Customer_update] 
( @Id int,
@Firstname nvarchar(40)=,
@Lastname nvarchar(40)=,
@City nvarchar(40)=null,
@Country nvarchar(40)=null,
@Phone nvarchar(20)=null

)
as 
begin 
update Customer 
set FirstName=ISNULL(@Firstname,FirstName),
LastName=ISNULL(@Lastname,LastName),
City=ISNULL(@City,City),
Country=ISNULL(@Country,Country),
Phone=ISNULL(@Phone,Phone)
where Id=@Id 
end
```